# Can this system of equations be solved?

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm doing some Lagrange multiplier examples that I thought up and I was trying to think of an example where the method of 'solving the constraint explicitly' fails. I'm trying to maximize

$$f(x,y)=x^2 y + y^2 x$$

given the constraint

$$g(x,y)=xe^x +ye^y -1 =0$$

I made this constraint up because I'm pretty sure it can't be solved explicity for either variable. Now, I form the Lagrange function

$$F(x,y)=f(x,y)-\lambda g(x,y)$$

and differentiate w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ and solve the system of equations:

$$0=2xy+y^2- \lambda (x+1) e^x$$
$$0=2xy+x^2- \lambda (y+1) e^y$$

Theoretically I should be able to solve this for $x$ and $y$ that depend on $\lambda$ and then choose the $\lambda$ so the constraint is actually satisfied, but I don't know how to do that.

Instead, I tried 'solving' for $\lambda$ from the first one and substitute into the other and I get

$$(2xy+y^2)(y+1)e^y=(2xy+x^2)(x+1)e^x$$

Dividing by $xy$ (this excludes any points on either axis), I get

$$(2+\frac{y}{x})(y+1)e^y=(2+\frac{x}{y})(x+1)e^x$$

Which is like saying $$h(x,y)=h(y,x)$$ where $h$ is either side of the previous equation. Again, I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: You might want to try contour plots.

Comment: Your last equation clearly shows that $x=y$ is one solution.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint and function are unchanged by swapping $x$ and $y$, so the point with $y=x$ must be a maxima or minima, in this case $x=W(\frac{1}2)$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Comment: Did you use CAS?

Comment: Can you please elborate why the extremum of a symmetric function is on $y=x$? I find I'm lacking a geometrical intuition when it comes to this.

Comment: And might I ask for an answer along the lines of Lagrange multipliers? Thanks very much.

Comment: The symmetry on exchange of $x,y$ does not in general guarantee that all critical points $(x,y)$ satisfy $y=x$.

Comment: $y=x$ doesn't have to be the only extremum, but in this case it is a maximum. With Langrange multipliers the easiest way again is to use $y,x$ symmetry.  [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximise+x%5E2y%2By%5E2x+given+xe%5Ex%2Bye%5Ey%3D1)

Comment: ^So you did use CAS, right?

Comment: What's CAS? Also, I should probably have specified that I'm actually interested in solving the system, not just knowing whether one exists. And preferably in a way that would be doable with just pen and paper, without resorting to actually graphing the function and constraint.

Comment: You can't solve equations like $$x=e^x$$ by pen and paper with arbitrary accuracy.